# How will I achieve the below data structure using Multidimensional Arraylist or HashMap in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, multidimensional-array

```
{
  "TC_01": {
    "step": "TS01",
    "keyword": "navigate",
    "object": “search_fare"
  }
  "TC_02": {
    "step": "TS02",
    "keyword": "Verify text",
    "object": “text_header_Traveler"
  }
}
```

How will I achieve the following data structure using Multidimensional Arraylist or HashMap in Java? Please provide your suggesstion

Comment: What do you want to do with the data?  Have you tried anything so far that you're having trouble with?

Comment: That particular example looks like a Map<String, Map<String, Object>> to me, but in most real apps, you would want to translate that into actual business objects with real properties.

Comment: This will not be in json format, rather an array list...I need to build this structure in a loop to execute the inner data list for running statements based based on the keyword

Comment: The above data set will be build by reading from an excel file. I will need to pass all the four data to a seperate method to write in an excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your code you´ll finde something called "code smell" (repeated code). You have your own structure of three parameters that continue to repeat themselves: step, keyword and object. Just seeing that I suggest putting that in a class so as to have:

```
public class YourClass{

    private String keyword;
    private String step;
    private String object;

   //It´s your choice whether to have setters or have everything in through constructor

   public String getKeyword(){
       return this.keyword;
   }

   .... //continue with getters for step and object
}
```

Now you can have your regular structure of hashMap so as to have Map which means that they key for looking into your map will be a string "TC_01", "TC_02" and when you get YourClass returned, all you have to do is invoke .getKeyword() ... to get the rest of your information.

Example:

```
YourClass yourClassVariable = new YourClass();
yourClassVariable.setStep("TS01");
yourClassVariable.setKeyword("navigate");
yourClassVariable.setObject("search_fare");

Map<String,YourClass> mp=new HashMap<String, YourClass>();

// adding or setting elements in Map by put method key and value pair
mp.put("TC_01", yourClassVariable);
```

:)

Answer (score 3):

make a class/type for

```
{ "step": "TS01", "keyword": "navigate", "object": “search_fare" }
```

Say `YourClass`

```
class YourClass{
  String step,keyword,object;  //type string is just example
...
}
```

then you need a map `Map<String, YourClass>`

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, TCObject> = new HashMap<String, TCObject>;
```

Where, TCObject is a class that contains fields:

```
private String step;
private String keyword;
... etc ...
```

Comment: I think its a Map as every object corresponds to a String.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. It is a map, if those Strings are unique. If he doesn't care about that, he could use just the list.

Comment: A list results {{"step": "TS01", "keyword": "navigate", "object": “search_fare"}, {"step": "TS02", "keyword": "Verify text", "object": “text_header_Traveler"}}, without the expected strings before each object.

Comment: Thanks..Will try based on your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help...

```
        
public class TC{

    private String keyword;
    private String step;
    private String object;
  //setters
  //getters
}


TC tc=new TC()

tc.setStep("TS01")

tc.setKeyword("navigate");

tc.setObject("search_fare");

Map map=new HashMap();

map.put("TC_01",tc);
```